# Miworkplace : An error has occured. See the log file (RPG)

Tags: rpg

I am learning RPG, and I have to install `Miworkplace`, I am trying to understand the tutoriel below:

https://miworkplace.com/docs/

1. I installed `Java11` on my Windows 10

https://miworkplace.com/docs/Requirements

2. I downloaded `Miworkplace` on my desktop
3. When I launch `MiWorkplace`, I have an error message ?

*"An error has occured. See the log file"*

[image]

I don't understand the problem ??

I deleted 3 times the folder -> workspace but I always have the same problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MiWorkplace is an Eclipse based application. You will find the log file in the workspace folder: workspace/.metadata/.log

https://miworkplace.com/docs/Log_File

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of MiWorkplace required the installation of Java prior to running MiWorkplace. This was documented on the download page.

Recent versions of MiWorkplace do not require a separate installation of Java anymore.

The latest version of MiWorkplace/Pub400 can be downloaded here: https://miworkplace.com